# Jolt Transformer Grouping based on the fields inside the object

Tags: json, transform, jolt, transformer-model

I wanted to group the input array objects based on the fields `profileName`, `assetLevel1`, and `assetLevel2`.

**Input:**

```json
{
  "product": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "entity": "entity1",
      "productID": "productID1",
      "productName": "productName1",
      "unitPrice": "unitPrice1",
      "assetLevel1": "Equities",
      "assetLevel2": "US Large Cap Equity",
      "profileName": "Beginner Level"
    },
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "entity": "entity3",
      "productID": "productID3",
      "productName": "productName3",
      "unitPrice": "unitPrice3",
      "assetLevel1": "Fixed Income",
      "assetLevel2": "Global Aggregate Funds",
      "profileName": "Novice Level"
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "entity": "entity2",
      "productID": "productID2",
      "productName": "productName2",
      "unitPrice": "unitPrice2",
      "assetLevel1": "Equities",
      "assetLevel2": "US Large Cap Equity",
      "profileName": "Beginner Level"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My current spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "product": {
        "*": "@profileName.@assetLevel1[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```json
{
  "Beginner Level": {
    "Equities": [
      {
        "US Large Cap Equity": [
          {
            "assetLevel1": "Equities",
            "assetLevel2": "US Large Cap Equity",
            "entity": "entity1",
            "id": "id1",
            "productID": "productID1",
            "productName": "productName1",
            "profileName": "Beginner Level",
            "unitPrice": "unitPrice1"
          },
          {
            "assetLevel1": "Equities",
            "assetLevel2": "US Large Cap Equity",
            "entity": "entity2",
            "id": "id2",
            "productID": "productID2",
            "productName": "productName2",
            "profileName": "Beginner Level",
            "unitPrice": "unitPrice2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Novice Level": {
    "Fixed Income": [
      {
        "Global Aggregate Funds": [
          {
            "assetLevel1": "Fixed Income",
            "assetLevel2": "Global Aggregate Funds",
            "entity": "entity3",
            "id": "id3",
            "productID": "productID3",
            "productName": "productName3",
            "profileName": "Novice Level",
            "unitPrice": "unitPrice3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

I have tried the above but unable to proceed as I am a newbie in this.

Comment: You have `Global Aggregate Funds` in the `Equities`. But their object is `US Large Cap Equity`. It seems your desired output is wrong. If not, please explain the relation between them.

Comment: thanks you for the feedback, corrected the text as it was a result of copy-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "product": {
        "*": "@profileName.@assetLevel1.@assetLevel2[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "MANY"
      }
    }
  }
]
```